# :focus doesn't do anything on my form inputs

Tags: css

Below is my code. When I select the input, it has the default black border instead of the color I picked below. I changed `:focus` to `:hover`, and I do get my desired border when I hover over the input. Any ideas?

```css
input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 145, 0);
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: Try adding `outline:none` to `input:focus`. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outline` is hiding your border.

When you put it to `outline:none` you have your orange border.

```css
input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

input:focus {
    outline:none;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 145, 0);
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the default styling applied by the browser

```
input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    outline: none; /* Remove the default focus outline */
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 145, 0);
    outline: 2px solid transparent; /* Add custom focus outline */
}
```